# Filter by checkbox show/hide div link jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have my jquery checkbox filter that works by showing/hiding the div, when I added an `<a href="#"></a>`the checkbox no longer shows/hides the div

2 of the div's are links to demonstrate, the other 2 purposefully not links to show they work.

Question is what needs to be added to the jquery to enable the checkbox to act on the div's when they are inside `<a href>`

I tried `var selectedDivs = $('#Categories > .linkkk > div').hide();` but this didn't seem to work

https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/22/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="High" data-category-type="high">High
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="low" data-category-type="low" > Low
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="low" data-category-name="bread" > bread



</div>

<div id="Categories">
    <a href="#" class="linkkk"><div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pizza">high</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pasta">low</div></a>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pizza">low</div>
    <div data-category-type="high" data-category-name="bread">bread</div>
</div>

$('.checkbox ').on('click', function (e) {



var $this = $(this),
    $links = $('.checkbox');

if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
    $this.removeClass('selected');
} else {
    $this.addClass('selected');
}

 var selectedDivs = $('#Categories > div').hide();
 var anySelectedCheckbox = false;
 $.each($links, function (k, v) {

$this = $(v);

if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
    anySelectedCheckbox = true;
    var cat = $this.data('categoryType');
    var nam = $this.data('categoryName');
    selectedDivs = selectedDivs.filter('[data-category-type="'+cat+'"],   [data-category-name="'+nam+'"]');
}

});
selectedDivs.show();

if(!anySelectedCheckbox) {
$('#Categories > div').show();

}


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/f7srx0dd/24/))

You're using a [css child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) which will not find the `div` if it is not a direct descendant of `#Categories`. This...

```
var selectedDivs = $('#Categories > div').hide();
```

Should be this...

```
var selectedDivs = $('#Categories div').hide();
```

Or, to be more specific, you could use this...

```
var selectedDivs = $('#Categories > div, #Categories > a').hide();
```

Or, if you want every direct descendant of `#Categories`, you can use this...

```
var selectedDivs = $('#Categories > *').hide();
```

Or, if you want to specifically hide the div within the anchor, you can use this...

```
var selectedDivs = $('#Categories > a > div').hide();
```

Comment: On my code it doesn't apply display:none, it uses flexbox and will keep the div in the column it appears in, I have updated the fiddle with my actual code, I don't have the jquery filter working now, could you please let me know how I can get this working? Thanks - https://jsfiddle.net/s1e93j92/3/

Comment: I'm presuming this is because of flexbox, the box container is left in place so I need to adjust the div that hides, I need to hide the box

Comment: yes except this hides the div's on checkbox select where as it should hide the div's that don't match. e.g if you select high it hides all div's with that value whereas it should actually show them all

Comment: I have managed to get this working by using `var selectedDivs = $('.grid-cell ').hide();`

Comment: Thank you, you were a massive help in me getting this working!

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap `div` with `a` selector `#Categories > div` doesn't work anymore, so you can't filter those nodes.

The simplest solution is to fix HTML markup like this:

```
<div id="Categories"> 
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pizza">
        <a href="#" class="linkkk">high</a>
    </div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pasta">
        <a href="#">low</a>
    </div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pizza">low</div>
    <div data-category-type="high" data-category-name="bread">bread</div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/23/

If however you still want to wrap `div` with `a` then you can do this:

```
<div id="Categories"> 
    <a href="#" class="linkkk" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pizza">
        <div class="hide">high</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pasta">
        <div class="hide">low</div>
    </a>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pizza">low</div>
    <div data-category-type="high" data-category-name="bread">bread</div>
</div>
```

and use `#Categories > *` selector:

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/26/

Comment: my actual code is a little more complicated, i was trying to simplify it for ease, https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/29/ is my actual code that I need to filter `#categories > * ` makes all div's disappear instead of filtering?

Comment: If you use `#Categories > *` selector then you need to move `data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pizza"` to a tag.

Comment: #caterogies > a > div works , I now need to apply a css class `{display:none}` to my hidden div's when filtered to remove the space they take up  , any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedDivs = $('#Categories div').hide();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/30/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="bread" data-category-name="bread" > bread

<div data-category-type="bread" data-category-name="bread">bread</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/31/